# Jquery UI range silder in rails app

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a small problem with a slider I use for time range.

When I move one of the handlers and then the second the first one changes it's value a tiny bit. (5 min in my case)

Here's my code

```
function slideTime(event, ui){
    var minutes0 = parseInt($("#slider_range").slider("values", 0) % 60);
    var hours0 = parseInt($("#slider_range").slider("values", 0) / 60 % 24);
    var minutes1 = parseInt($("#slider_range").slider("values", 1) % 60);
    var hours1 = parseInt($("#slider_range").slider("values", 1) / 60 % 24);
    $("#log_times_from").val(getTime(hours0, minutes0));
    $("#log_times_to").val(getTime(hours1, minutes1));
}

function getTime(hours, minutes) {
    var time = null;
    minutes = minutes + "";  
    if (minutes.length == 1) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
slideTime();

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slider_range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1439,
        values: [540, 1020],
        step:5,
        slide: slideTime
    });

})
```

Any ideas on why the handlers move when I move the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, by compering it to the code in the jqueryUI documentation for Range slider

This solves the problem. I use ui.values instead of selecting the id everytime

```
function slideTime(event, ui){
    var minutes0 = parseInt(ui.values[ 0 ]  % 60);
    var hours0 = parseInt(ui.values[ 0 ]  / 60 % 24);
    var minutes1 = parseInt(ui.values[ 1 ]  % 60);
    var hours1 = parseInt(ui.values[ 1 ]  / 60 % 24);
    $("#log_times_from").val(getTime(hours0, minutes0));
    $("#log_times_to").val(getTime(hours1, minutes1));
    $("#time").text(getTime(hours0, minutes0) + ' - ' + getTime(hours1, minutes1));
    $("#time1").text(getTime(hours0, minutes0) + ' - ' + getTime(hours1, minutes1));
}

function getTime(hours, minutes) {
    var time = null;
    minutes = minutes + "";  
    if (minutes.length == 1) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slider_range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1439,
        values: [540, 1020],
        step:5,
        slide: slideTime
    });

})
```